# PHP/MySQL Performance Testing with Just PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, web-server, performance

I'm trying to diagnose a server where the website is loading very slowly, but unfortunately my client has only provided me with FTP access.

I've got FTP access so I can upload PHP scripts, but can't set up any other server side tools.

I have access to phpMyAdmin, but not direct access to the MySQL server. It is also unfortunately a Windows server (and we've been a Linux shop for over a decade now).

So, if I wan to evaluate MySQL & disk speed performance through PHP on a generic server, what is the best way to do this?

There are already tools like: https://github.com/raphaelm/php-benchmark or https://github.com/InfinitySoft/php-benchmark

But I'm surprised there isn't something that someone has already set up & configured to just run through and do some basic testing of a server's responsiveness.

Every time we evaluate a new server environment it's handy to be able to compare it to an existing one quickly to see if there are any anomalies. I guess I'd just hoped that someone else had written up a script to do this already. I know I have, but that was before Github when there was a handy place to post scraps of code like this.

Originally posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321498/php-mysql-performance-testing-with-just-php but it was recommended that I re-post it here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run real diagnostics you're going to need proper access. There's no getting around that and you need to convey that message to the client. Any results you might get by scripting through a web server, be it IIS, Apache or anything else, will not give you meaningful results because you have no way of knowing what other layers or processes are involved.

Once you have benchmarks for the underlying system you can run some crude benchmarks on MySQl but only when you specify the conditions and create an appropriate testing script. Right now you would have no way of knowing why any particular query might be slow because you can't know  at which point that slowness was caused.